# CSS file not linking up with my html file

Tags: php, html, css

[image]

Here's a screenshot. I tried putting the style.css in the same folder as my sign.php file, and changed the href to "style.css" and then it **worked**. I don't know why it won't link up if it is out of the folder. What could be the problem here?

Did I mistype the path?

Comment: the question is not clear

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov how could i clarify it? Would I this be better: The CSS does not apply to my HTML?

Comment: It's a path issue. In this case the ole relative path vs absolute path. If you have your document root set correctly you could use /assets/css/style.css. Or you could define it and use it as part of the path.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yee thx bro i figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go back one directory.

Your PHP file is in `users/sign.php` so to load the css you need to add `../` before your css path to go back to your root. Or you can add `<base href="">` and add the root path in the href

Comment: thanks brother, cant believe im so stupid. worked like a charm

Comment: Your welcome, mistakes like this are easy to make when you write alot of code